# How can I import a selfmade class into my gwt project?

Tags: java, xml, gwt

I am working at a gwt tutorial and now i must Import a class/Project on my gwt Project. In my gwt Project i have the class "Sortierer-GWT" where is my entry Point. In this class i want to call a method, which is in another class. This class is written by my own and is called "UserInput". The class UserInput also Needs other classes. All this classes are in the Right Folder for Import. But if i Import the UserInput class like this:

```
Import eingabe.UserInput;
……
UserInput read = new UserInput();
```

The Compiler says error (No source code is available for type eingabe.UserInput; did you forget to inherit a required module?). Should i Import the other classes which are used for UserInput or should i write something in my .XML data to fix this error?

Comment: Add your class in the same package your EntryPoint is located. This will remove the error message.

Comment: okay but then i must add 14 classes to this package, because UserInput Needs this classes

Comment: thx it works. But how can i print my Array on the screen with gwt. I tried:   TextBox.setText(list) , but it doesnt work

Comment: The transpiler needs all of the classes to transpile the source. So, yes, you have to add them all. In case you need them on the client and server side, you need to put the classes into the shared package.

Answer (score 1):

There are many places with a lot of useful informations. Take a look here: https://github.com/TDesjardins/gwt-knowledge, https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1cr-rYGz58ngC6sgOy8c7oErhaj0VdLUHk9Y5mcvgrP0/edit#slide=id.p, https://dev.to/ibaca/modern-gwt-first-steps-509k, https://gwt.zeef.com/awesomegwt and of course [www.gwtproject.org](http://www.gwtproject.org).

And here you get in contact with other GWT developers: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt

If you would like to create a 'larger' GWT-poject, you can try the Nalu Project Generator: http://www.mvp4g.org/boot-starter-nalu/BootStarterNalu.html

(Attention: there is a bug due to an update in Domino-UI 'setLeftAddon' -> 'addLeftAddOn')

The project generator will create a slightly larger project, that might help you to understand how to organize a GWT project.

Regarding your question on how to display an array:

- GWT: http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox
- Domino-UI: https://demo.dominokit.org/home

And here, you will find an example project, using Domino-UI, Domino-rest and Nalu. It is a three pager, with server access and displaying a list of data: https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu-examples/tree/master/devkexample